# How do bash's logical operators work (or why don't they work here)?

Tags: bash, boolean

I have the following wrapper script:

```
#!/bin/bash

$local_time=`date +%H%M`
if [ $local_time -ge 1430 ] && [ $local_time -le 2230 ] ||
   [ $local_time -ge 0300 ] && [ $local_time -le 0400 ]
then
   echo 'pass'
else
   echo 'skip'
fi
```

The idea being to create a wrapper script that runs a script between two disjoint time intervals. Each of the expressions being OR'd is evaluated correctly, however, when I OR both expressions, the test fails.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two problems

1. You don't prefix your variables with a `$` when you assign to them, only when you *expand* them
2. You need to enforce operator precedence with parens `( )`

Also, since you're already using `bash`, might as well use its better syntax with the `(( ))` construct that allows you to use the comparison operators `< > == !=` and you can use `$()` for command substitution instead of the backticks/gravemarks

```
#!/bin/bash

local_time=$(( 10#$( date +'%H%M' ) ))
if (( ( local_time >=    1430 && local_time <=    2230 ) ||
      ( local_time >= 10#0300 && local_time <= 10#0400 )    ))
then
  echo 'pass'
else
  echo 'skip'
fi
```

Numbers that start with a zero are interpreted as octal.
Also, any number that start with 0 and contains an 8 or 9 will print an error.
Prefixing (10#) solves that.

Comment: A good introduction to more "modern" Bash is this: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide

Comment: I like this syntax much better!. What syntax was I using?. I was under the impression that was bash syntax?

Comment: @skyeagle bash is a POSIX compliant shell and you were using [POSIX Shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html) syntax which is a subset of what `bash` can do.

Answer (score 0):

bash does not have "logical operators"; those are "conditional chains". Logic belongs in the test.

```
if [[ ( 10#${local_time} -ge 10#1430 && 10#${local_time} -le 10#2230 ) || \
      ( 10#${local_time} -ge 10#0300 && 10#${local_time} -le 10#0400 ) ]]
then
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to enforce proper precedence with a couple of parenthesis:

```
#!/bin/bash

local_time=$(date +%H%M)
if ( [ "$local_time" -ge 1430 ] && [ "$local_time" -le 2230 ] ) ||
   ( [ "$local_time" -ge 0300 ] && [ "$local_time" -le 0400 ] )
then
   echo 'pass'
else
   echo 'skip'
fi
```

Reason: Inside an AND-OR list `&&` and `||` have equal precedence.
Note: Inside `[ ]` numbers that start with 0 are not interpreted as octals.

Other changes:

- The left side of an equal should have just the variable name (No `$`).
- It is recommended to use `$()` instead of ``` `` ```.
- Quote variables inside `[ ]`.