# Running variable string match against grep search?

Tags: linux, shell, grep, sh

I've defined the variables here to shorten the logic a little. The wget works fine (downloads the correct file) and grepping for tar.gz works in the wget.log

The issue is the match to another file!

Basically, if it's on a blacklist I want it to skip!

```
var1=https://somewebsite.com/directory
line1=directory

sudo wget -O wget.log https://somewebsite.com/$line1/releases

if grep -q "tar.gz" wget.log | "$var1" -ne grep -q 
"https://somewebsite.com/$line1" banned; then
    echo "Good Job!"
else
    echo "Skip!"
fi
```

Comment: Which shell exactly are you using? `sh` usually refers to a POSIX-compatible shell, but `bash` is often the default shell on Linux systems. I personally prefer `fish`. Anyhow, all of them differ in syntax, even if just slightly. Further, none of that really depends on the OS underneath, so the `linux` tag you applied is wrong.

Comment: What is `"$var1" -ne grep -q` supposed to mean, and why are you piping the output of the first `grep` to it?

Comment: `grep -q` doesn't produce any output, so it makes no sense to pipe its output to another command.

Comment: Can you include samples of the `wget.log` and `banned` files? It would be much easier to diagnose and prescribe a solution if your question included an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: wget.log will be just a big dump of info, searched to see if it contains any tar.gz files, the second file "banned" is just a file containing full links that should not be checked against again.

Also sorry about incorrect tags :)  Still learning definitions on where to put things.

Comment: [How do bash's logical operators work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4763460/608639), [Precedence of the shell logical operators &&, ||](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/88850/56041), [Unix Boolean Operators ( &&, -a, ||, -o )](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20449680/608639), [How to do a logical OR operation in Shell Scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4111475/608639), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `&&` to test if both of the `grep` commands succeed

```
if grep -q -F 'tar.gz' wget.log && grep -q -F -x "$variable" banned
then
    echo "Skip!"
else
    echo "Good Job!"
fi
```

I've used the `-F` option to `grep` because none of the strings we're searching for are regular expressions, they're fixed strings. And I used `-x` in the second `grep` to match the whole line in the blacklist.

Comment: So this syntax works, but the purpose of the tar.gz is just a generalized search, not used as a full variable match, however, the second grep (against banned) is indeed an exact string match to another file.

Comment: That's why I didn't use `-x` on the first `grep`.

Comment: I think I'm a little rusty on conditional if/then.  So tar file should be the first check in the if/then, then there needs to be another check in banned.

echoing tarfile gives me gibberish right now(which is expected cause it's only meant to match if it finds tar.gz in the dump) but if I grep against banned, the format is going to be different I think.

So I'm thinking it should be

IF tar.gz matched in file AND $var1 NOT found in banned, THEN

echo good job

else, banned, fail

fi?

That is the syntax I'm having issues constructing :)  Thank you for any advice

Comment: Why are you even doing the `wget` if the site is banned?

Comment: I think I understand what you want now, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Yeah that looks like it!  Let me test :)

I was getting "too many arguments" with this!  if grep -q "tar.gz" wget.log | [ "$var1" != grep -F -x "$var1" banned ]; then

Comment: I still don't understand why you have a pipe there. If you mean *or* it should be `||`.

Comment: Your solution fixed it.  Thank you for the proper way to handle double expression with variable :)